# How to make view model and model communicate?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am using MVVM pattern for my app. The model actually runs a set of test in parallel and keeps tab of the status of the test including its result. I want the status and result to be displayed in the view. I am stuck at desiging the view model.

The problem is that there are lots of classes and sub class hierarchy in the model in which all the required data to be displayed in the view are stored. Those data are dynamic. 
I am not sure how to design the view model now.

I was thinking along these lines - Create a new data structure in view model which reflects what is to be shown in the view and get all the view model will dig through the model to get the required data. In this case I am confused how the model will update the view model whenever a data changes. Or how do the model and view model communicate with each other given that the data are stored in different class and sub classes.

Comment: Can your model fire an event when it changes its state? Ideally models are dumb and are manipulated by something else. They shouldn't mutate themselves.

Comment: Actually I can have more than one test running at a time - so essentially more than one model at a time and the user can chose which data to view. I can make the model fire an even whenever it changes. If models are suppose to be dumb - is there something wrong with my design? Should the logic to run the test reside in VM?

Comment: Every model needs to have a viewmodel corresponding to it which handles the events and fires its own notify property changed and then you can have a parent view model which can contain these child view models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view model should have references of all models which required to show data on the view. Then view model should handle events from model classes and fire NotifyPropertyChanged event.

If your view is complex and require lots of models, then you can consider to split your view in multiple views and corresponding view model.

Comment: I have different data that can change at different time. I think it will be difficult to subscribe to events for each of them. Is there any other way in which the VM and Model can communicate?

Comment: You can fire NotifyPropertyChanged event from model classes. Then handle these events in view model and fire NotifyPropertyChanged from view model again. Your view model must know when something changed in model. Other ways is check properties of model classes from view model periodically and then check which properties has been changed and fire NotifyPropertyChanged event for those properties.

Answer (score 1):

You say the user chooses which data to view, so I imagine your VM could hold an array of Models and an index indicating which is the 'active' one, and only communicate with that one.

For that communication, a solution could be to pass to the model an Action to call when new data is available, and that Action would that trigger a NotifyPropertyChanged in the VM. This would work especially well if you make sure only the 'active' model has that Action while in the others it would be null meaning 'don't trigger updates'.